# chef exception handling -> simplest way to use chat_message (LWRP) on :run_failed

Tags: exception, chef-infra, chef-recipe, lwrp

We have chef-client scheduled on our nodes and I'll like to set up exception handling so the error is reported in our chat.

Previously I got help here to write a LWRP which posts to chat

```
chat_message do
    message "Hello, World"
    channel "deployments"
end
```

Now, in my recipe `deploy_stuff`, I would like a *simple* way to report exceptions with the LWRP `chat_message`, and I tried this:

```
# set up error handler
Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_failed do |exception|
    chat_message ":exclamation: chef run_failed on #{Chef.run_context.node.name}: #{exception.message}"
  end
end
```

However it didn't work:

```
Running handlers:
[2016-10-14T10:13:48+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-10-14T10:13:48+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 10 resources updated in 20 seconds
[2016-10-14T10:13:48+02:00] ERROR: undefined method `chat_message' for #<#<Class:0x00000005e1ef60>:0x00000005e1ee70>
[2016-10-14T10:13:48+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

What does `undefined method chat_message` mean - can't I use a LWRP here?

I am sure the `chat` cookbook is included because other code in my recipe calling `chat_message` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the event handler just runs plain old Ruby code, not the recipe DSL. You could put the important logic in a library method and call it from both the resource and the event handler.

Comment: Can the library method then use DSL? Since `chat_message` in turn uses `execute do \n command "curl ...." \n end`

Comment: Nope, you can call plain Ruby from the DSL but not vice versa.

Comment: You would need to use the chef::http client API.

Comment: Hmm, ok. What about an alternative way to build an exception handling mechanism... one that can use DSL? Thanks so far... :)